# show tab struct programming C

Tags: c, struct, tabs

I'm doing a exercice, they want me to show a tab struct.
The file **ft_strs_to_tab.c** will convert stdin argument in a tab struct then the file **ft_show_tab.c** will show the size, the string and the string copy of each elements of the tab struct, the tab struct will end with a string == NULL.
I can only use the write function. The file **ft_stock_str.h** will connect my file **ft_strs_to_tab.c** and **ft_show_tab.c**.

But I had this message: 
*Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ft_show_tab", referenced from:
      _main in ft_strs_to_tab-587ca3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)* 
 
**ft_stock_str.h**

```
#ifndef FT_STOCK_STR_H
#define FT_STOCK_STR_H

typedef struct s_stock_str
{
    int size;
    char    *str;
    char    *copy;
}       t_stock_str;

void    ft_show_tab(struct s_stock_str *par);
t_stock_str *ft_strs_to_tab(int ac, char **av);
void    ft_putchar(char c);
void    ft_putnbr(int nb);
void    ft_putstr(char *str);

#endif
```

**ft_strs_to_tab.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ft_stock_str.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_strlen(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(str[i])
        i++;
    return(i);
}

char    *ft_strdup(char *str)
{
    char    *s1;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
        i++;
    if(!(s1 = malloc(sizeof(*s1) * (i + 1))))
        return(NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        s1[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    s1[i] = '\0';
    return(s1);
}



struct s_stock_str *ft_strs_to_tab(int ac, char **av)
{
    t_stock_str *dest;
    int i;

    if(!(dest = malloc(sizeof(*dest) * (ac + 1))))
        return(NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (i < ac)
    {
        dest[i].size = ft_strlen(av[i]);
        dest[i].str = av[i];
        dest[i].copy = ft_strdup(av[i]);
        i++;
    }
    dest[i].str = 0;
    return(dest);
}
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    ft_show_tab(ft_strs_to_tab(ac, av));
    return(0);
}
```

**ft_show_tab**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ft_stock_str.h"
void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb >= 10)
    {
        ft_putnbr((nb / 10));
        ft_putchar((nb % 10) + 48);
    }
    else if (nb < 10)
        ft_putchar((nb % 10) + 48);
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        write(1, *tr, 1);
        str++;
    }
}

void    ft_show_tab(struct s_strock_str *par)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (par[i].str)
    {
        ft_putnbr(par[i].size);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        ft_putstr(par[i].str);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        ft_putstr(par[i].copy);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your platform/editor/IDE/compiler/OS? How do you compile?

Comment: What the heck is a "tab struct"????

Comment: OT: `av[0]` will be the program name. Do you really want to pass that to `ft_strs_to_tab()`? You probably want `ft_show_tab(ft_strs_to_tab(ac-1, av+1));`.